# Call and match data on mysql database PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a coupon matching site which is kinda similar to a lotto. The problem I am encountering is how to call the data from a database. I want to **freecoupon** if match with **coupon** which is generated using a form field **text_value** would trigger the function I created

```
$sql = "SELECT value FROM couponCode";
$freecoupon = $conn->query($sql); 

$coupon = text_value;      
if ($coupon == $freecoupon ) {    
    percentchance();  
}
```

Comment: most of that is invalid php, start by fixing that

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: syntax is valid except for the equal sign that I forgot

Comment: just corrected it forgot to include the $ sign as well

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you made quite a few edits to this and are aware of the mistakes that I pointed out below, it seems that your problem might not be within the code you shared, but within another part of your code. I'd recommend some basic debugging to see exactly where the issue is and then update us if you need further assistance.

---

## Old Answer

You're not doing the comparison correctly. You need to use two equal signs when comparing values. A single equal sign is mainly for assigning values to variables.

```
if ($coupon == $freecoupon) {
    percentchance();
}
```

You might also want to remove `id` from the sql statement or drive into the freecoupon variable more when comparing it to the coupon variable, otherwise it won't compare correctly since you're assigning the full results of the query statement to the freecoupon variable.

Also, don't forget the dollar signs for `$freecoupon` and `$coupon`